# Will the current needed for core saturation (transformer) increase with applied voltage?

Tags: transformer, saturation, ferrite

I was going through [one of the research papers](https://patents.justia.com/patent/9705421) based on self-excited push-pull converters.

The line below is taken from the paper:

> the current needed for core saturation rapidly increases with increases in the operating voltage.

Does core saturation depend on the voltage? Will the saturation limit increase as the applied voltage goes up?

$$B = μ_0\cdot μ_r\cdot H = {{μ_0\cdot μ_r\cdot N\cdot I}\over L}$$
The magnetic flux for core saturation needs to be a constant based on this formula, but the paper says that this is not the case and that core saturation is a function of the input voltage, and that the saturation limit will vary with the applied voltage.

How is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not got time for an answwer - the assertion sounds incorrect. The english in the paper is poor, I wonder if some terms have been mistranslated? It is also somewhat 'breathless', so appears to be quite a low quality patent. To first order, core saturation occurs at a specific net core current, the magnetising current, which occurs at a specific voltage and frequency. However ferrite cores are often run at much below saturation, as heating limits the usable fields first. Will try to read more of the paper later. Without graphs and figures, it's difficult to comprehend

Comment: I agree with Neil, the quote is clumsy and misses the point. If I were you, I'd remove the link to the patent and ask your own question in your own words. So, ask your own question if you want a decent answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does core saturation depend on the voltage?

Yes. The core saturates easier with increased voltage. This comes from the Faraday equation:

$$
V = N\ A \ \frac{\Delta B}{\Delta t} 
$$

where,

- N is the number of turns.
- A is the cross sectional area of the core that the winding is on.
- B is the flux density
- V is the voltage.

Note that V and B can generate each other. In your case, V is the supply voltage and it's already there, applied across the winding. So V will generate B.

N and A are constants. So if you keep the frequency (or the time interval) constant, increased voltage will generate more flux swing. And more flux swing means closer to saturation.

> Will the saturation limit increase as the applied voltage goes up?

No. It's related to the material. It may change with temperature but it doesn't change with the applied voltage. If something like this is possible then this will change the entire design process of the switching power supplies.

---

It appears that you misunderstood what's written on the paper. It doesn't say that the saturation flux density increases with the applied voltage. It says that, if the applied voltage increases then the **current required for saturation** will increase.

Comment: Thank you that really helps.

Comment: I have yet to see an inductor where saturation current has anything to do with voltage. The core doesn’t care much for how you generate the ampere-turns. As long as you get enough ampere-turns, it will saturate at the same point, assuming no pre-existing magnetization. The Faraday law isn’t very relevant in explaining this, since the concept of “ease” of driving an inductor to saturation is entirely foreign to me. As long as you reach enough amp-turns at DC, the core will saturate eventually. How much voltage it takes depends on things not related to core saturation but to the winding.

Answer (score 2):

> *How is this possible? Am I missing something?*

This is what the patent paper says: -

[image]

And, after reading the whole paragraph a couple of times I have to conclude that the words highlighted are not meaningful.

What the highlighted statement should be implying is that as the core saturation point increases (due to an increase in AC voltage applied) the current peaks can get substantially larger (and non-linear) than what would be implied by the increase in voltage. This [wiki gif file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Power_Transformer_Over-Excitation.gif) might help: -

[image]

The blue current waveform is what flows when a sinusoidal voltage is applied to the primary winding AND significant core saturation is occurring i.e. the AC applied voltage has reached a level where the inductance of the primary reduces due to core saturation. When this happens (at the peak of the AC voltage waveform) substantially larger current peaks are taken.

This is what I believe the quoted statement in the question is trying to say.

> *Does core saturation depend on the voltage?*

It directly depends on the magnetic permeability of the core, the magnetization current, the number of turns and the mean length of the magnetic field around the core. This can be linked to the applied voltage providing the AC frequency is known because then, the inductance can be calculated and current calculated incrementally throughout the waveform. Alternatively you can look at the core BH curve and figure it out in a more practical way.

> *Will the saturation limit increase as the applied voltage goes up?*

The saturation shape of the core is dependent on the core, and the applied H field (ampere turns per metre). It is also somewhat dependent on core temperature for ferrites (for example).

Comment: Thank you. This helps.